# Is python 3.4 supported by rospy?

Tags: ros, rospy, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm working now in python 2.7, but I want to use module in python 3.4.
Can it cause problems if I upgrade python version?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261239/is-python-3.4-supported-by-rospy?/) by [matansar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29912/matansar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of the core of ROS is tested against both Python2 and Python3. As you get to more leaf packages the level of testing is lower. If you are going to switch there are likely going to be issues that need to be debugged and preferrably submitted back upstream with a patch but there shouldn't be any major blockers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0